# Spring-boot config properties to avoid use of beans

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, web-config

For now I have this code on my boot class

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bundle = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    bundle.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages");
    bundle.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    bundle.setCacheSeconds(1);
    return bundle;

}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}
```

I want to know if it´s possible to do that via properties like we do with dataSource and how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

From the spring-boot [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

```
# INTERNATIONALIZATION (MessageSourceAutoConfiguration)
spring.messages.always-use-message-format=false # Set whether to always apply the MessageFormat rules, parsing even messages without arguments.
spring.messages.basename=messages # Comma-separated list of basenames, each following the ResourceBundle convention.
spring.messages.cache-seconds=-1 # Loaded resource bundle files cache expiration, in seconds. When set to -1, bundles are cached forever.
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8 # Message bundles encoding.
spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=true # Set whether to fall back to the system Locale if no files for a specific Locale have been found.
```

Comment: it didn´t worked. Do i need something different on pom.xml?